# How to get the root window where a widget is placed from that widget?

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I am creating a Tkinter-based GUI. I created a custom button widget, and I'd like to get access to the root (main) window from there.

I know about the `.master` attribute, and I can use it to achieve what I want (see the code below). But because the button might be placed very deep inside of dozens of frames, I have to get .master recursively until I get `None`. I wonder if there is a cleaner way to get the main window of the program?

```
import tkinter as tk


class MyButton(tk.Button):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(bg="white", *args, **kwargs)

        root_window = self.master
        while root_window.master:
            root_window = root_window.master
        assert isinstance(root_window, tk.Tk)

        # in my particular case, the above code is equivalent to this:
        assert isinstance(self.master.master.master.master, tk.Tk)

        # but I'd like to be able to use something like that:
        # assert isinstance(self.root_window, tk.Tk)

root = tk.Tk()
frame1 = tk.Frame(root)
frame2 = tk.Frame(frame1)
frame3 = tk.Frame(frame2)
my_btn = MyButton(frame3)

for widget in (frame1, frame2, frame3, my_btn):
    widget.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Calling `winfo_toplevel` on any widget will give you the root window of that widget.